# How to spool data into an excel workbook using SQL developer

Tags: sql, excel, spool

I am trying to export large data from sql developer using spool into an excel workbook and my query is like this:

```
spool "D:\\Data\\Party.xlsx"
SELECT PARTY_NO, ACCOUNT_REF FROM HZ_PARTIES
spool off;
```

But after export completion, I could not open excel sheet, I'm getting an error as

```
Excel cannot open the file 'Party.xlsx' because the file format for the file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.
```

Comment: Are you sure `spool` can export directly to an Excel file, as far as I know, you may export as a textonly file such as csv etc.?

Answer (score 0):

File type should be `.xls` and not `xlsx`